# Excel VBA, custom search with Evaluate(MAX(IF)) condition - mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a 'custom' search macro so that user can quickly find the latest date for a corresponding project in a worksheet full with titles of communications (emails, letters, notes, etc) for different projects.

The sheet has several columns, the ones of interest are `B:B` in which dates are listed and `F:F` in which the communications are listed.

The idea is the user enters a keyword via InputBox, the macro checks `F:F` for the communication with that keyword and checks `B:B` whether that communication has the latest date for this specific keyword. The search continues until one is found. The output is a `MsgBox` with the title and the corresponding date.

Everything works except the condition to find the latest date, `(Evaluate("MAX(IF)"))` gives me a mismatch error.

I've tried `WorksheetFunction.Max` and `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal` as well, but they do not give the latest date.

*Edit: thanks a lot for the edit suggestions*

```
Sub Proj_Find()

    Dim ProjName As Range
    Dim UserInput As String
    Dim LatestDate As Double

    UserInput = InputBox(Prompt:="Give the keyword for the searched project" & vbCrLf & "Entrez un mot clé pour le projet recherché", Title:="Latest Date Search", Default:=DefaultInputString)
    Set ProjName = Cells.Find(what:=UserInput, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not ProjName Is Nothing Then
        LatestDate = Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & ProjName & " <>"",B3:B1000))")
        MsgBox "The last communication is '" & ProjName.Value & "' - dating " & ProjName.Offset(0, -4)
    Else
        MsgBox "Project not found         " & vbCrLf & "Projet non trouvé" 
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & ProjName & " <>"""",B3:B1000))")`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> LatestDate = Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & ProjName & " <>"",B3:B1000))")
> ```

`ProjName` is a `Range` object; that `& ProjName &` concatenation is therefore implicitly `Let`-coercing the object into a `String`. Make that explicit:

```
LatestDate = Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & ProjName.Value & " <>"",B3:B1000))")
```

That formula yields `Error 2029` though, i.e. a `#NAME!` worksheet error - you're getting a *type mismatch* because the returned `Variant/Error` can't be coerced into a `Double`:

```
Dim LatestDate As Double
LatestDate = CVErr(xlErrName) ' type mismatch
```

The `#NAME!` error is because the `ProjName.Value` isn't enclosed in quotes, so the Excel calc engine treats it as a named range, and fails to find it.

```
=MAX(IF(SomeName<>"",B3:B1000))
        ^^^^^^^^ needs quotes!
```

The solution is, [as Slai suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559331/1188513), to enclose the `ProjName[.Value]` in double quotes, *and* to properly escape them (i.e. double them up).

Comment: Neat, thank you for the clarification. I'll have to reread it again later to fully grasp it :)